# Kaleidoscope graphic/plot in python

Tags: python, plot, graphics

I was wondering if anyone knows a python module that would allow me to create something like this:

[image]

https://service.destatis.de/Voronoi/PriceKaleidoscope.svg

I've tried plotly without any success.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: this looks more like [voronoi diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram) then [caleidoscope](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/25310/6868) to me ...

Comment: My bet is that input is some kind of tree (with percentages of something) each branch of tree takes it portion of the disc area, its children takes portion of area of its parrent and so on .... and you just cycle some predefined colors, border strength might be just hardcoded for first few levels of tree

Comment: @Gago-Silva did you find a way to do it? I am interested :)